# Defining a Lyx-inset, that always has full line width in the editor

Tags: lyx, lyx-layouts

**Correction:** *In the original text I wrote that floats are displayed full-width. This was an error; Just like the "flexi-insets" created with `InsetLayout` they are only displayed in full-width when they contain more than one line. Hence the workaround also doesn't work as intended.*

In LyX there are some builtin layouts in `Resources/layouts/stdlayouts.inc` that when inserted fill the full width of the editor. This behaviour applies to the prototype layout `Box` and the `Box:<SpecificName>` family of layouts. Similar behaviour applies to floats.

I wanted to define a local layout that encloses a paragraph into the `widetext` environment. The layout

```
InsetLayout WideText 
    LyXType          Custom
    LabelString      WideText
    LatexType        environment
    LatexName        widetext
    Decoration       classic
    LabelFont        
        Color        blue
        Size         Small
    EndFont
    MultiPar         true
    OptionalArgs     0
    Preamble
        \RequirePackage{widetext}
    EndPreamble 
End
```

does this, but in LyX the inset will be displayed only as wide as its contents -- which is a poor representation of the actual environment. I'd prefer my inset to be displayed in the Style of boxes and floats, without being either: Boxes *always* include a minipage environment (which is undesirable) and floats cause undesirable changes to the preamble unless supressed by a hack (which hence may break in future versions of LyX).

As a workaround I am using the layout

```
Float
    Type         widetext
    GuiName      widetext
    IsPredefined true
End
```

where `IsPredefine` supresses an entry in the preamble, that clashes with the definition of the `widetext` environment. The inset is then listed in *Insert → Float* The results look like this

[image: Widetext Inset vs pseudo-float]
and the compiled behaviour is correct in both cases.

But is there a clean solution to obtain the desired behaviour without the float-hack?

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, this is not possible for Flex insets.

Looking at the source code, we see that Inset.h has the following

```
/// Is the width forced to some value?
virtual bool hasFixedWidth() const { return false; }
```

In the inheritance chain to InsetFlex, this member function is never overriden.

Boxes have the following (see InsetBox.cpp):

```
bool InsetBox::hasFixedWidth() const
{
    return !params_.width.empty();
}
```

If you change that return to be `return false;`, then they will not have the full page width that you're talking about either.

Note that when I copy/paste your definition into Document > Settings > Local Layout, I get the following output on my terminal:

```
insets/InsetLayout.cpp (206): Flex insets must have names of the form `Flex:<name>'.
This one has the name `WideText'
Ignoring LyXType declaration.
LyX: Unknown InsetLayout tag [around line 2 of file  current token: 'Custom' context: '']
LyX: Unknown InsetLayout tag [around line 11 of file  current token: 'OptionalArgs' context: '']
LyX: Unknown InsetLayout tag [around line 12 of file  current token: '0' context: '']
frontends/qt4/GuiDocument.cpp (571): Format 49
InsetLayout "Flex:WideText"
    LyXType          Custom
    LabelString      WideText
    LatexType        environment
    LatexName        widetext
    Decoration       classic
    LabelFont        
        Color        blue
        Size         Small
    EndFont
    MultiPar         true
    ResetArgs   1
    Preamble
        \RequirePackage{widetext}
    EndPreamble 
    ResetsFont true
End
```

You might want to correct these errors.

Finally, note that I have little experience with layouts in LyX, so any of the above could be off. You should join our mailing list at lyx-users@lists.lyx.org and post further questions there. The experts there know more than I do.